# Dicrete Mathematics (Languages Grammars)

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

> Given Grammar $G$ with non-terminal symbols $N= \{S, A, B, C\}$ and terminal symbols $T=\{a,b\}$ and derives $P=\{ S \to B , B\to aBa, B\to bA, A\to bA , A\to C, C\to a \}$ and start symbol is S. Find the Language L(G) of grammar G and describe it as a set.

I think that $L(G) = \{abbaa, bba, ba\}$ . What do you think people?

But there is something that I REALLY cant understand.

Can we say this: $B\to aBa \to aaBaa \to aaaBaaa \to etc$   ?

this can continue to eternity, what can I do about it?

I mean every single of these words $(aBa , aaBaa , aaaBaaa .....)$ could lead us probably to words with terminals only $(abbaa, aabbaaa, aaabbaaaa )$ which looks like a pattern but different pattern compared to $\{abbaa, bba, ba\}$ .

I am so confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The derive $B \to e$, where $e$ denotes the empty word, should be added.

Comment: @user64494 do you imply that the question is wrong? Or should I include that e in my answer? More confused :/

Comment: @ John. Brn: I think the formulation of $P$ is not correct. The derive $B \to e$ should be added to $P$ and $e$ should be added to $T$. The empty word contains no symbol.

Comment: @user64494 I double checked the question and I think it is right. In fact, it is the same notation that Cl Liu uses on his book "discrete mathematics". What is the purpose of e ? Supposedly there was that e, how would the answer be according to you. And why B -> e and not A -> e as well?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Hey sir, mind checking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ S \to B  \text{ (1)}\\ B\to aBa \text{ (2)}\\ B\to bA \text{ (3)}\\ A\to bA \text{ (4)}\\ A\to C \text{ (5)}\\ C\to a\text{ (6)}$

You should follow the way a string is made by applying rules of the grammar. In *this* grammar, starting with $S$ you should apply rule 1. Now you can apply rule 2 zero or more times, then you have to apply rule 3, then you can apply rule 4 zero or more times, then you have to apply rule 5 and after that rule 6.

So lets right this down:

Applying rule 1 we have:

$B$

Applying rule 2 zero or more times we have:

$a^nBa^n,n\geq0$

Applying rule 3 we have:

$a^nbAa^n,n\geq0$

After applying rule 4, $m$ times we will have($m\geq 0$):

$a^nbb^mAa^n,n,m\geq0$

Now we should apply rules 5 and 6, this gives us the final form of the strings of the language:

$a^nbb^maa^n,n,m\geq0$

Or equivalently:

$a^nb^{m+1}a^{n+1},n,m\geq0$

You should continue derivations until *no nonterminal* remains, only then the derivation is finished.

Note that derivations of strings is not always as straight forward as this grammar.

Comment: Hey! thanks mate. With your logic , using rule 4 we would have $a^nb^mAa^n,n,m\geq0$ . But can we say that L(G) = {$a^nb^mAa^n$ ,$a^nbAa^n$ , $a^nBa^n$ , n,m >=0}  ? I think that L(G) can contain only non-terminal strings, right??

Comment: @John.Brn I have updated my answer. I think it answers your questions now. Strings of language are made up from *terminal symbols*. It would be good to reread the related parts in your book. Good luck.